# ember: bound attributes are evaluated on the wrong tag

Tags: attributes, ember.js, bind, handlebars.js

I want to highlight a selected navigation element and so I have bound an attribute to the li of a navigation bar like this:

```
<li {{bindAttr class="isHome:active"}}>{{#linkTo 'home'}}Home{{/linkTo}}</li>
```

The attribute is evaluated correctly and adds the right class - but not to the li, instead it gets added to the a which results in:

```
<li class="" data-bindattr-1="1"><a id="ember237" class="ember-view active" href="#/home">Home</a></li>
```

Is there something wrong here with the markup or is this a bug?!

Answer (score 3):

There are two things happening here:

1. The `isHome` property is not getting applied to your `li`
2. The `{{linkTo}}` helper, coincidentally, adds an `active` class to links when the route it points to is active.

This is making you think that the `active` class is getting moved. You can try logging the `isHome` property (via `{{log isHome}}`) to see whether it is true as you expect.

Comment: thx! that is helpful, there is lots of automagic in ember, that I am not yet aware of...